# Clustered bar chart with Highcharter (R) plot year and categories

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have the following simple example of a clustered bar chart, by year:

```
library(highcharter)

year <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
black <- c(12, 15, 23, 16, 11)
asian <- c(3, 12, 63, 46, 21)
white <- c(5, 45, 44, 44, 4)
hispanic <- c(23, 25, 44, 16, 112)

df <- data.frame(year, black, asian, white, hispanic)

highchart() %>% 
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = df$year) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="White",data = df$white) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Black",data = df$black) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Asian",data = df$asian) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Hispanic",data = df$hispanic)
```

Producing:

[image]

I want the years to be on top of the chart, and then each category labeled not by year, but by race, like this, more or less:

[image]

Same data as I have on the chart, just different formatting.  I see no examples in highcharter that explain how to do this.  Is it possible in highcharter?

### Update

I tweaked my code:

```
highchart() %>% 
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_xAxis(opposite = TRUE, gridLineWidth = .3, categories = df$year) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="White",data = df$white) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Black",data = df$black) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Asian",data = df$asian) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Hispanic",data = df$hispanic)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

How do I make the chart so that the series names (white/black/asian/hispanic) actually show up on the x-axis (repeating for each series, under the bars -- see above photo in original question) instead of just in a legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moving the xAxis categories, use `opposite: true` options. To enabled grid, set the `xAxis.gridLineWidth`. Alternatively, you can use the `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to draw them. When it comes to the series name labels, my proposition is to use formatted `dataLabels` and align them via `chart.render` event.

Here is the JS config you can base on:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    marginBottom: 60,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.points.forEach(function(p) {
            if (p.dataLabel) {
              p.dataLabel.attr({
                y: chart.plotHeight + p.dataLabel.options.height / 2 + 5
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: [{
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    opposite: true,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: 'grey',
    categories: [
      '2010',
      '2015',
      '2020',
    ]
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        formatter() {
          return this.series.name
        }
      },
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]
  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3]

  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5]

  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3y0ar58k/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

---

EDIT:

The label's rendering

```
hc_chart(events = list(render= JS("function() { var chart = this; chart.series.forEach(function(s) { s.points.forEach(function(p) { if (p.dataLabel) { p.dataLabel.attr({ y: chart.plotHeight + p.dataLabel.options.height / 2 + 5 }); } }); }); } "))) %>%

hc_plotOptions(
  column= list(   
pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels = list(
allowOverlap: true,
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
formatter = JS("function(){
 return this.series.name                          
")
)    )
  )
) %>%
```

Comment: Thank you!  But, how do I translate this to R?  I suppose I just need to figure that out..

Comment: Hi, II see that you figured out the axis part. I've added the `dataLabels` part. Please note, that I'm not the R developer so you will need to revise this code if necessary. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've figured it out but I've re-worked @magdalena's answer a bit to get it working in R and added a few minor details. Credit goes to her.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df = df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("white", "black", "asian", "hispanic")) %>%
  mutate(name = str_to_title(name))

highchart(type = "chart") %>%
  hc_chart(spacingBottom = 80) %>%
  hc_xAxis_multiples(
    list(opposite = TRUE, gridLineWidth = .5, categories = df$year), 
    list(title = list(text = "Race"), top = 100)
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, hcaes(x = year, y = value, group = name), type = "column", showInLegend = F) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(render = 
    JS("function() { 
      var chart = this
        chart.series.forEach(function(s) { 
          s.points.forEach(function(p) { 
            if (p.dataLabel) { 
              p.dataLabel.attr({ y: chart.plotHeight + p.dataLabel.options.height / 2 + 5})
            } 
          })
        })
      }"
  ))) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    column = list(
      groupPadding = 0.05,
      borderWidth = 0,
      dataLabels = list(
        # allowOverlap = TRUE,
        enabled = TRUE,
        rotation = -90,
        formatter = JS("function() {return this.series.name}")
      ) 
    )
  )
```

[image]